# Правильное употребление глагола "проверить"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Словари дают примеры типа "**проверить что-то**". А корректно ли говорить "**проверить, что...**" (например: проверить, что результат не равен нулю)? Не происходит ли здесь подмена "удостовериться" на "проверить"?

Answer (score 1):

Действие *проверки*, которое выражает данный глагол, предполагает существование как минимум двух *альтернатив* и выявляет, какая из них имеет место (в общем случае может оказаться и что-то неожиданное). Глагол может употребляться и без прямого дополнения (хотя он и переходный), например:

> **проверить, что** происходит на самом деле

Однако подстановка после "**что**" *единственного* ожидаемого результата ("проверить, что результат не равен нулю") приводит к видимому просторечию. Действительно, возникает ощущение подмены глагола с другим смыслом (убедиться, удостовериться). Возможное здесь выражение с глаголом "**проверить**":

> **проверить**, (не) равен ли результат нулю

(отрицание здесь возможно в зависимости от того, какой из двух результатов более ожидаем)

К сожалению, трудно найти источник толкования смыслов для каждого глагола, возможно, в каком-нибудь справочнике по стилистике похожий пример может попасться.